# Polar form of CR equation

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, cauchy-riemann-equations

We know that, by applying a coordinate change, we have the polar form of CR-equation which is given by:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} &= \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}, \\ 
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} &= - \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}.
\end{split}
$$

This equation can be used to check whether a function is holomorphic at some point, correct? I find there is no reference makes the theorem in a formal statement, and I found a that this equation can not check whether $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $z = \{z| z\in \Bbb{R}_{-}\}$ since over this axis the re-parametrization $u(r,\theta )$ is not continuous, correct? Is there some formal criterion for holomorphic function in polar coordinate?

Comment: On the negative axis just change the domain of $\theta$ to $(0,2\pi)$ say and the parametrization is continuous; C-R equations are local so you need a parametrization in the neighborhood of the point you want to check them, while also they involve derivatives so all the argument ambiguity (its multivalent nature by two pi multiples) disappears anyway

Comment: thank you I have worked it out,I think too much about it,the CR equation in polar coordinate is just for computational benefit.